# Convert Array-looking variable to Data in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdata, uint

I want to convert an (at least I think) array of UInt8 values to Data.

Using Data(bytes: variable) does not work here.

Here's the type of the variable:

```
po type(of: obj.variable)   
(Swift.UInt8, Swift.UInt8, Swift.UInt8, Swift.UInt8)
```

It seems that this isn't an array of UInt8 but what type is it and how can I convert it to a Data?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a tuple with 4 `UInt8` values.

Comment: Superb! Indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `obj` is a tuple of four `UInt8` values.

You can access elements of the tuple as follows:

```
let obj: (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8) = (2, 4, 6, 8) // let obj be a tuple of four UInt8 values
obj.0  // 2
obj.1  // 4
```

As `Data` is effectively a `Collection` of bytes, it can be initialized from a sequence of `UInt8` values.

So the easiest solution would just be to create an `Array` from the elements of the tuple and initialize a `Data` value from it:

```
let data = Data([obj.0, obj.1, obj.2, obj.3])
```

This is however not the most general solution and only works when the tuple only contains `UInt8` values.

A more general approach would be to convert the tuple to an `UnsafePointer` first and create a `Data` value from it:

```
let data = withUnsafePointer(to: &obj) { ptr -> Data in
    return Data(bytes: ptr, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: obj)
}
```